# is this the right phrasing for designation in email or letter

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-patterns, syntactic-analysis

My signature in all my official emails & letters state my designation as

> Sr.Digital Marketing  Executive.

One of my work colleagues told me its wrong & change it to

> Sr.executive digital marketing

I am confused as to how I should state my designation -

> Sr.Digital Marketing Executive

or

> Sr. Executive Digital Marketing

which one would be appropriate? - according to me its the first one which states sr.dgm exec

Comment: Both are correct. Punctuation changes with structure. 'Sr. Digital Marketing Executive', 'Sr. Executive, Digital Marketing' -- note the comma.

Comment: and spaces btw punctuation

Comment: It would depend on what your formal title is within the company, but it should be capitalised.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether "Digital Marketing" is an adjective (describes your job) or a noun (identifies the group or department to which you belong). If it's an adjective, your signature should be:

> Senior Digital Marketing Executive

and if it's a noun, your signature should be:

> Senior Executive, Digital Marketing

This version is just a tiny bit pompous unless you work in a group or department called Digital Marketing.

Also, you should spell out Senior rather than abbreviate it to Sr. There may be a need to abbreviate it on a printed business card if space is tight, but there is no need to abbreviate it in an email sig where there is plenty of room to spell it out.